# Why is a watch off by one tick in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like the height of one element to be synchronised with the height of another element. The contents of the second element change with time.

An example of such code is below (and in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/honartnp/)):

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    growingText: ''
  },
  watch: {
    growingText: function() {
      document.getElementById("square").style.height = document.getElementById("text").offsetHeight + 'px';
    }

  }
})

setInterval(
  function() {
    Vue.nextTick(function() {
      vm.growingText = vm.growingText + 'hello world ';
    })
  },
  500
)
```

```css
div[id="root"] {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}
div[id="square"] {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div id="square" :style="{height: h+'px'}">
    x
  </div>
  <div id="text">
    {{growingText}}
  </div>
</div>
```

As visible in that example, the changes of the height of the upper `div` (with the blue background) are off by one with the changes of the height of the lower `div`. The behaviour is the same whether I use [`Vue.nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) or not.

**Is this by design or could I change something to have a true synchronization?**

*Note: I am not sure that my use of "tick" is correct, do not hesitate to modify the title if this is not the case.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) so the content is displayed when retrieving the div size: https://jsfiddle.net/ncx2y0no/

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  document.getElementById("square").style.height = document.getElementById("text").offsetHeight + 'px';
})
```